# Sci-Fi TV episode about a man who doesn't know he's an alien

Tags: identify-this-episode, the-twilight-zone, the-outer-limits

I think this was an Outer Limits or Twilight Zone episode.  I remember watching this in the early 2010s, but I think the episode was a repeat of an earlier series, possibly from the 1960s.

In the episode, a man visits a small town to investigate unusual activity.  While there he becomes suspicious of the activity of the townspeople.

He hooks up with a woman, and they discover an alien spaceship in the desert.

The spaceship chases the couple, and eventually they take shelter in the town, where they have to hide from the townspeople who are aliens in disguise.

Eventually they are captured and taken to the spaceship.  The man is put into a machine, and his memories are restored.  Turns out he was an alien all along, but had forgotten (not sure if that was deliberate).

Can someone help me identify this episode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [A Day in Beaumont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Day_in_Beaumont), a segment from the first season of the 80s *Twilight Zone* revival.

> **In 1955, Kevin and Faith Carlson are travelling through the country** when they see a meteorite strike over the next hill. On investigation, **they discover an alien spacecraft** manned by insectoid beings. The Carlsons race to the nearest town to report what they've seen, but the local sheriff insists that a military plane has crashed. [...] Kevin notices that the hands of the army personnel are all deformed in the same unusual way, and so are the sheriff's. [...] **When they try to leave the town, they are stopped by the combined efforts of the alien spacecraft and the townspeople. The townspeople reveal that they and the Carlsons are aliens**, and that this is a training simulation of an invasion of Earth. However, **some of the aliens suffered memory loss** and forgot their roles, and the "Carlsons" were among those.

Here it is:

Comment: Ah hah! That's the one.  Set in 1955... that's why I thought 1960's.  Well, that and the cheap special effects... :-D